# Keep windows reference in memory

Tags: vimscript, buffers, vim-windows

I am writing a plugin which needs to have two windows displayed at the same time:

```
 _______
|   |   |
| A | B |
|___|___|
```

I need to keep in memory a reference to those windows as I execute my plugin. This is because I need to be able to jump between the two windows automaticaly.

I use the `winnr()` function that returns the current window number, which I can use later like so:

```
let s:winA = winnr()
new
let s:winB = winnr()

" stuff

" go to window A
execute s:winA . "wincmd w"
```

But in this case, both variables will have the value `1`, this is because the `winnr()` return the position of the current window in the tab display.

I tried to use the `bufnr('%')` which return the buffer number for the current buffer. This is great, but when I do:

```
let s:bufA = bufnr('%')
new
let s:bufB = bufnr('%')

" stuff

" go to buffer A
execute 'buffer '. s:bufA
```

The current window load the buffer, and the cursor will not jump to the existing window containing the buffer.

---

Here is my question:

How to store permanent information about windows so the cursor can jump on it later?

Answer (score 7):

I think what you are looking for is the function `win_getid()` combined to the
function `win_gotoid()`.

[`:h win_getid()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#win_getid())
says:

> win_getid([{win} [, {tab}]])
>
> Get the window ID for the specified window.
>      When {win} is missing use the current window.
>      With {win} this is the window number.  The top window has
>      number 1.

The advantage of these functions is that ID is linked to a window and does not
change when the position of the window is changed

Your script would become something like:

```
let s:winA = win_getid()
new
let s:winB = win_getid()

" stuff

" go to window A
call win_gotoid(s:winA)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't store a window number reliably because it changes every time a window is created and destroyed.  You can use `winbufnr()` if you know the buffer's ID.

When the buffer doesn't matter, I use a window variable to keep track of the windows I open:

```
new
let w:_plugin_variable = 1
```

The variable above is just a boolean, but you could use your own identifier if you want to keep windows paired to each other.  For example:

```
let w:_plugin_variable = ['parent', 123]
new
let w:_plugin_variable = ['child', 123]
```

The first item being the relationship and the second as some special identifier.  This way is useful if both windows might contain the same buffer but have different settings/purposes.

To find the windows, you just iterate over all window numbers to get the variable you're looking for:

```
for i in range(1, winnr('$'))
  let id = getwinvar(i, '_plugin_variable', -1)
  if id != -1
    " Do something with the information.
    break
  endif
endfor
```

In the loop above, `i` is the window's number.  You can get settings from the window with `getwinvar(i, '&textwidth')` or switch to it with `execute i 'wincmd w'`.

The same thing can be done with tabs using `tabpagenr()`, `tabpagewinnr()`, `gettabvar()`, `gettabwinvar()`, etc.

Comment: Nice! Do you think there's performance drawback from doing this?

Comment: @nobe4 I'm pretty sure that any performance impact would be unnoticeable since you'd be dealing with dozens of windows at most (per tab) in realistic scenarios.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5219213) (useful in a wider context).